# Insert a column in exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I have an existing xlsx file, with 4 columns. [ A, B, C, D ]. I want to insert a new column between A and B to have => [A, B, C, D, E] where B is new and C, D, E are the old [B, C, D]. I haven't found a method in the doc page

Doc : https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the method  called "spliceColumns". It works perfectly.
For my example => workbook.spliceColumns(2, 0, [])

Comment: do we need to commit the changes or the columns are removed directly after `spliceColumns`?

Comment: If I remember well, it's already removed. To be sure, try to log the length of your columns :)